# Surface 3/win 10 how to put file shortcut on tablet home?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-surface, tablet-mode

Is it possible to put a link to a folder or file as a square on tablet mode?  I tried send to> desktop but it only puts it on the desktop mode desktop.

Comment: try this: http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/how-add-web-shortcut-windows-10-start-screen

Comment: Done... Steps in Answer below.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> 1. Open the web site for which you want to create a shortcut in
>      Internet Explorer, right-click on a blank part of the page, and
>      choose "Create Shortcut." NOTE: This DOES NOT work in Microsoft
>      Edge, since Edge doesn't offer the ability to generate a web page
>      shortcut (yet). The shortcut will be created on the Windows 10
>      Desktop (this is your only option).
> 2. Right-click on the Windows 10 Start button and choose Run.
> 3. Using the Shell command, 
>      use the following command to open the Windows 10 Programs folder: Shell:Programs
> 4. Go back to the Windows 10 Desktop, right-click on the newly created web shortcut and choose Copy.
> 5. Jump back to the open Programs window, and choose Paste to install
>      the shortcut.
> 6. Placing the web shortcut into the Programs folder, causes it to show
>      up in the All Apps list in the Start Menu.
> 7. Locate this new web shortcut and drag it to the Start Screen.

Source: http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/how-add-web-shortcut-windows-10-start-screen

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). You need to correctly quote cited material. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill will make sure it won't heppen again.